# Need a tool to automatically indent and format SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, formatting

In my current project I've been inherited with lots of long (1200+ lines) SQL Server stored procedures with some horrible indentation and formatting which makes them almost unreadable. Is there some tool that I can use to automatically format these and make them more readable? I don't want to go through it manually and indent it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a couple -- no idea how well they work, unfortunately...

http://www.wangz.net/gsqlparser/sqlpp/sqlformat.htm (free)

http://www.sqlinform.com/ (free for personal use)

Comment: SQLinform works very well, actually. Lots of options, you can lay out code the way you like best.

Comment: Here is an article that introduce how to format SQL in your own program automatically : http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/sql-beautifier-format-sql-in-your-own-program/

Comment: SQLinForm now has a free desktop version for SQL statements up to 100 lines which should be fine in most cases

Answer (score 9):

Try using [ApexSQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx). It integrates into SSMS and it’s a free tool.  Good thing about it is that it allows to save formatting options and share them with the team so all of you use the same settings for code.

Answer (score 5):

Try [redgate SQLPrompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Prompt/index.htm). It has a 14-day trial.

Answer (score 5):

[Red Gate "SQL Refactor"](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Refactor/index.htm) Very good. We bought it

Or

[SSMS tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) Free, but we don't use the layout features

Comment: Does not do indentation, only changes case :(

Answer (score 2):

Check out Sql assist:

It has some format feature.

http://www.roundpolygons.com/Default.aspx?PageContentID=5&tabid=92

I would suggest downloading the evaluation version to see whether it fits your need.

Answer (score 1):

Try www.softfrontiers.com/Downloads/ReIndenter.shtml
Free (or donate) and download.

Works on C# and SQL Server code.

Is very fast and doesn't change the code except for indentation and endblock comments where missing and possible.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the following link to format and indend your SQL Server Code online. http://sqlserverlearner.com/online-tools/tsql-code-formatter

Its working great!!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using dbForge SQL Complete for a while now and am pleased with it($99 and free version).  The formatter works from within Visual Studio and SMSS.  It also has a handy code completion feature that works better the the standard one built into SMSS.
http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/ordering.html