# SQL Server 2005: How to automatically include database name and brackets in queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssms

Good day,

In SQL Server 2005, when I write a new query, I like to drap and drop table and column names from the object explorer. However, when I drag and drop a table, is there a way to automatically include the database name?

(example: when I drag and drop the table Table1 in the query designer, I would like to have  Database1.dbo.Table1 instead of just Table1)

Also, is there a way to automatically include '[' and ']' around the column and table names?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, not from drag and drop from object explorer.

One of the tools suggested in this question may help:

[Need a tool to automatically indent and format SQL Server stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686394/686416)